# ADC interrupt doesnt work with TIMER3 interrupt that generates PWM

Tags: embedded, stm32, adc, stm32f4, nucleo

I've been trying to write some code on STM32F411re usign IAR workbench in order to learn more about Cortex. I tried to implement TIMER3 PWM mode (center-aligned) with TIMER 2 being called every (half a second, second doesnt matter as much performing LED blink) and ADC performing continious regular conversion on one channel. I've tried to implement it all using interrupts. TIMER3 interrupt is inteded to be generated on Overflow and underflow and within ISR i would change PWM width with value from ADC (changed with potentiometer).

**Problem that i faced while creating project seems to be that, when TIMER3 is activated, program doesnt hit breakpoint ( does not enter) ADC ISR routine nor within any line of program within while(1) loop. When i comment TIMER 3, program normally goes through ADC ISR.**

````
#include "stdio.h"
void Uart6Configuration(void);
void send_data (uint8_t c);
void init_PWM(void);
void init_ADC(void) ;
void init_Interupts(void);
unsigned long vrednost_ADC=0;
float temp=0;
unsigned long counter=0;
int main()
{
 
 RCC->APB1ENR|=(1<<0); //TIMER 2
 RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1<<0); //GPIOA    
 RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1<<2); //GPIOC
 GPIOA->MODER|=(1<<10); 
 RCC->APB2ENR|=(1<<5);    // USART6[PC6,PC7]
 
 /* Define TIMER-a 3 */
 RCC->APB1ENR|=(1<<1); //TIMER 3
 GPIOB->MODER|=(1<<9);
 GPIOB->AFR[0]|=(1<<17);
  
 TIM2->PSC=89;
 TIM2->ARR=0xFFFF;

 TIM2->DIER|= (1<<0); 
 TIM2->EGR|= (1<<0);

  Uart6Configuration();
  init_PWM();   
  init_ADC();    
  init_Interupts();
  TIM2->CR1|=(1<<0);
  TIM3->CR1|=(1<<0);
  while(!(TIM2->SR & (1<<0)));
  ADC1->CR2|=(1<<30); // START ADC

/*GLAVNA PROGRAMSKA PETLJA*/
  
 while(1)
 {
      counter++;
  if(counter>100000)
  {
    printf("AD konverzija=%f \n\r",temp); //Terminal I/O 
    counter=0;
  }    
 }
 
/* ************************/   
 
 return 0;
}
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void )
{


 if(TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)
  {
   TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; 
   GPIOA->ODR^=(1<<5);
   }
  TIM2->SR =0;
}
void Uart6Configuration (void) 
{
  
  
  GPIOC->MODER |= (2<<12);  //  --> Alternate Function for Pin PA11
  GPIOC->MODER |= (2<<14);  // --> Alternate Function for Pin PA12
  GPIOC->OSPEEDR|=(3<<12)|(3<<14);
  GPIOC->AFR[0] |= (8<<24);  //AF7 bitovi 8,9,10,11 PC6
  GPIOC->AFR[0] |= (8<<28);   //AF7 bitovi 15,14,13,12 PC7
  USART6->CR1=0;
  USART6->CR1|=(1<<13);
  USART6->CR1 &= ~(1<<12); 
  USART6->BRR=(3<<0)|(104<<4);  
  USART6->CR1|=(1<<2);
  USART6->CR1|=(1<<3);
}
void send_data (uint8_t c)
{
        
        while(!(USART6->SR & (1<<6)));
        USART6->DR=c;
              
}
uint8_t UART6_GetChar (void)
{
   /*********** STEPS FOLLOWED *************   
   1. Wait for the RXNE bit to set. It indicates that the data has been received and can be read.
   2. Read the data from USART_DR  Register. This also clears the RXNE bit 
   ****************************************/
   uint8_t temp;   
   while (!(USART2->SR & (1<<5)));  // wait for RXNE bit to set
   temp = USART2->DR;  // Read the data. This clears the RXNE also
   return temp;
}
void init_PWM(void)
{
 /*PB_4*/
   TIM3->PSC=15;
   TIM3->ARR=750;
   TIM3->CR1|= (1<<5)|(1<<6) | (1<<2); // PWM CENTAR EDGE MODE
   TIM3->CCER|=(1<<0); //Capture/Compare 1 output enable.
   TIM3->CCR1=500;   //DUTY CYCLE
   TIM3->CCMR1|=(1<<5)|(1<<6);  // PWM MODE bit 5 i6
   TIM3->DIER|=(1<<0);

}
void init_ADC(void) 
{
   RCC->APB2ENR|=(1<<8);  // Clock za adc 
   GPIOA->MODER|=(1<<2)|(1<<3);  // Analog mode PA.1
   ADC1->SQR3|=(1<<0);  // Choose channel ADC1/1
   ADC1->CR1|=(1<<5); //EOCIE interupt generates when ADC finish conversion
   ADC1->CR2|=(1<<1)|(1<<0); // Continious mode, ADC ON
}
void ADC_IRQHandler(void)
{
 
    vrednost_ADC=ADC1->DR;
    temp=(float)((vrednost_ADC/4095.0)*3.3) ;
     
}
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void )
{   

 if((TIM3->CNT & 10)<=0) // DETECTOVATI  UNDERFLOW
 {
    TIM3->CCR1=(vrednost_ADC/4095)*1000;
    TIM3->EGR|=(1<<0);
 }
}
void init_Interupts(void)
{
NVIC_SetPriority (ADC_IRQn, (13));
NVIC_SetPriority (TIM2_IRQn, 14); 
NVIC_SetPriority (TIM3_IRQn, 15); 
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn);  
NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC_IRQn );
}```
````

Comment: It is virtually impossible to review this code with all these magic numbers.  Almost all the places you have (1 << x), there is a constant for that in the same header file that defines the register names.

One thing that jumps out as very questionable is `((TIM3->CNT & 10)<=0)`.  The timer register has unsigned type so this will never be less than zero.  This means you are just testing whether the masked bits are zero.  Also, your mask is decimal which I presume is a mistake.

Comment: I am sorry if its inconvenient to read code. I will edit it as soon as possible. ((TIM3->CNT & 10)<=0) this part of code is mistake so i will correct it, but it doesnt solve my problem. Thank you for your time

Comment: Try to clear TIM3 interrupt flags.

Comment: Part of the problem were interrupt flags, so thank you.